# Typescript - Invoking subclass's instance method from base class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

I'm building a project (small game) and i'm trying to find solution for my issue.

I have code where i use base class Entity which has necressary methods for subclasses (objects) like movement, model rendering etc... Functions which are used in all other subclasses
F.e

- Entity -> Base Class,

  - SpellObject -> Subclass / Extends Entity
  - PlayerObject -> Subclass /extends Entity
  - UnitObject -> Subclass / Extends entity

In entity i have default movement method where i check collision but when the collision is hitted, i want to invoke subclass method onCollisionHit which is defined in XXXObject (For every object i need separated code)

My Code

Entity:

```
class Entity
{
    constructor(obj: EntityInterface)
    {
        ///
    }

    public doMove(...):void
    {
        // SpeedX SpeedY...
        // ...
        if (collisionHit)
            // getSubclass f.e PlayerObject.onCollisionHit()

        this.addPosition(speedX, speedY)
        //...
    }

    // ....
```

SpellObject/PlayerObject/...

```
export class xxxObject extends Entity
{
    constructor(obj:XXXInterface)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public onCollisionHit(...):void
    {
        // Do something (for SpellObject ->Call spell Disapear, for Player set MovementX/Y to 0..
    }
```

How can i invoke onCollisionHit from base class in this example? 
 One possible solution i found is to link subclass instance to variable of base class

- in Entity -> protected subclass;
- in xxxObject -> this.subclass = this; -> in doMove() -> when collision hit call -> if (this.subclass) this.subclass.onCollisionHit()

Im not sure if it is only a solution by wasting memory..
Thanks all for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `onCollisionHit` an abstract method of `Entity`, and make `Entity` itself abstract, since you seem to expect every Entity subclass to implement the method and presumably you should never be able to instantiate just a raw Entity.

```
abstract class Entity
{
    constructor(obj: EntityInterface)
    {
        ///
    }

    public doMove(...):void
    {
        // SpeedX SpeedY...
        // ...
        if (collisionHit)
            this.onCollisionHit();

        this.addPosition(speedX, speedY)
        //...
    }

    public abstract onCollisionHit():void;
    // ....
```

Then you can use e.g. `this.onCollisionHit()` from within `Entity` method implementations. If you have need to instantiate `Entity` instead of a subclass, you can ditch the abstract idea and just have a default (empty?) implementation of `onCollisionHit()` and have subclasses override it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is exactly what i was looking for.
Cheers!